# Finetuning (German) Bert. Is it underfitting?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, pytorch-lightning

With pytorch-lightning and transformers, I finetuned a Bert model on german service tickets. The dataset has the following size:

```
FULL Dataset: (1220, 2)
TRAIN Dataset: (854, 2)
VAL Dataset: (366, 2)
```

Every ticket can be in exactly 1 out of 10 categories. This is why my model is initilized in def **init** like:

```
#changing the configuration to X lables instead of 2
self.bert = transformers.BertModel.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)
self.drop = th.nn.Dropout(p=0.1)
self.out = th.nn.Linear(self.bert.config.hidden_size, NUM_LABELS)
self.softmax = th.nn.Softmax(dim=1)
self.loss = th.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction="none")
```

This produceds a probability distributuion over the 10 classes for each sample. As the forward function is:

```
 def forward(self, input_ids, mask):
    _, pooled_output = self.bert(
                                input_ids=input_ids,
                                attention_mask=mask
                        )
    output= self.drop(pooled_output)
    output = self.out(output)
    return self.softmax(output)
```

As a loss function torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss is defined and within the training_step called. With a Batch_Size of 16, logits.shape = [16,10] and batch['targets'].shape = [16] and batch['targets'] = [1,5,2,4,8,6,9,0,0,1,2,7,7,7,5,3]. **Is CrossEntropyLoss the right loss function?** And is the optimizer even working?

```
 def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    logits = self.forward(batch['input_ids'], batch['mask']).squeeze()
    loss = self.loss(logits, batch['targets']).mean()
    return {'loss': loss, 'log': {'train_loss': loss}}
```

Same goes for validation_step:

```
  def validation_step(self,batch, batch_idx):
      logits = self.forward(batch['input_ids'], batch['mask']).squeeze()
      acc = (logits.argmax(-1) == batch['targets']).float()
      loss = self.loss(logits, batch['targets'])
      return {'loss': loss, 'acc': acc}
```

In the end, the model produces the same probabilities no matter what input sequence it gets. Is this underfitting?

A example is:

```
model.eval()
text = "Warum kann mein Kollege in SAP keine Transaktionen mehr     ausführen?"
input = tokenizer(            
   text,
   None,
   add_special_tokens=True,
   max_length=200,
   pad_to_max_length=True,
   return_token_type_ids=True,
   truncation=True,
   padding='max_length',
   return_tensors="pt"
   )

input = input.to(device)

out = model(input_ids=input['input_ids'], mask=input['attention_mask'])
text, out

    --> ('Warum kann mein Kollege in SAP keine Transaktionen mehr ausführen?',
 tensor([[2.9374e-03, 3.1926e-03, 8.7949e-03, 3.0573e-01, 2.6428e-04, 5.2946e-02,
      2.4758e-01, 6.2161e-03, 3.6930e-01, 3.0384e-03]], device='cuda:0',
    grad_fn=<SoftmaxBackward>))
```

And another example is:

```
    ('Auf meinem Telefon erscheinen keine Nummern mehr.',
 tensor([[2.9374e-03, 3.1926e-03, 8.7949e-03, 3.0573e-01, 2.6428e-04, 5.2946e-02,
          2.4758e-01, 6.2161e-03, 3.6930e-01, 3.0384e-03]], device='cuda:0',
        grad_fn=<SoftmaxBackward>))
```

It is german, but as you can see, the predictions match exactly. Which is a shame :D And my problem.

Comment: Plot learning curves with training and validation data. That is the only way to tell if you're overfitting or underfitting.

Comment: How are you doing the finetuning?